# Setting the classpath java error

Tags: java, macos, classpath, environment-variables, agents-jade

I am trying to follow [this](http://jade.tilab.com/doc/tutorials/JADEAdmin/startJade.html) tutorial to be able to use Jade (Java Agent Development Framework). I am pretty new with java. I have a problem with this command: (I am using Mac OSx)

```
java -cp lib\jade.jar;classes jade.Boot -gui -agents ping1:examples.PingAgent.PingAgent
```

I get this error:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
       (to execute a class)
or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
       (to execute a jar file)
...
-bash: classes: command not found
```

I have set my environment variables like this:

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Applications/jade/classes
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/Applications/jade/lib/jade.jar
```

and here is the hierarchy of the folders:
[image]

If you need some more information to understand the problem please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding quotes around your class path: `java -cp "lib\jade.jar;classes" ...`. Without them, bash interprets the semi colon as the start of a new command, which causes the error message `-bash: classes: command not found`

**Edit**

It just struck me that you of course are running in *nix. Then the path separator would be `:`, not `;`. Then the quotes shouldn't even be needed. Semi colon is the path separator in Windows.

Comment: hey, then I get this Error: Could not find or load main class jade.Boot

Comment: That's a different error. Either your classpath is wrong, or you're running the command from the wrong folder (the folders are specified relative to the `jade` folder), or the class simply does not exist.

Comment: when I run java -cp lib/jade.jar jade.Boot -gui it works, if I add classes in the classpath it gives me the error.

Comment: Try using `:` instead of `;`

Comment: Now this works: `java -classpath lib/jade.jar:classes jade.Boot -gui -agents ping1:examples.PingAgent.PingAgent` , thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
java -cp "lib\jade.jar;classes" jade.Boot -gui -agents ping1:examples.PingAgent.PingAgent
```

Looks like bash is treating the ; as end of command and treats classes as a new command.

Answer (score 0):

The command is in Windows notation, not Unix one. On Unix systems You have to use lib/jade.jar instead of lib\jade.jar